# ORA-01427: single-row sub query returns more than one row in setting up parent child relation with GUID(sys_Guid())

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I want to make Id(varchar2) to guid type in parent child relation tree table.
I copied table like that

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (OLD_ID,
                         ITEM_NAME,
                         PARENT_OLD_ID
                         )
   SELECT 
      OLD_ID,
      NAME,
      PARENT_OLD_ID          
 FROM TEST_TABLE  ;
```

Then I wanted to update table to set new parent child relation like:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE A
  SET PARENT_GUID =
      (SELECT GUID
         FROM TEST_TABLE
        WHERE      OLD_ID = A.PARENT_OLD_ID);
```

The error I got is like :
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

I think more than two items are selected in subquery of the update statement above.

Is there any way resolve this problem out.

Thanks in advance.

Joon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a simple option is to select - for example - MAX(GUID) as

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE A
  SET a.PARENT_GUID =
      (SELECT MAX(t.GUID)                   --> this
         FROM TEST_TABLE t
        WHERE      t.OLD_ID = A.PARENT_OLD_ID);
```

but you should investigate what's going on - whether those "many rows" are the same (so MAX would fix it), or they are different so you'd rather not use that approach but fix data first.

Also, I'd suggest you to precede all column names with table aliases.

Comment: Preceding all column names with table aliases is a good idea with correlated sub-queries, as the scope of the column name is across both "tables" (might be another sub-query). Any typo could mean that you're only reading columns from one table failing the correlation part of what's trying to be achieved.